# How to set up a generic USB modem?

Tags: windows, macos, networking, usb-modem

I bought a couple years ago a USB modem in Italy (TIM branded, Huawei E1800) but now want to use it with a local sim in another country. The device by default first mounts as a mass storage device, offering to install the modem functionality - but that is bundled with some network specific crapware.

How can I set up the modem directly with the local settings (APN etc) of the network I'm using, and avoid installing any of the original software it arrives with? Answers for both Windows and OS X are welcome.

Comment: which country is the local SIM from that you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this device seems to be almost exclusive to Italy, based on google results. You will need the specific device drivers, and also a way to connect, normally using the "Connection manager" that is provided on the mass storage part of the device.

It is fairly possible to overwrite this using a firmware for the same device, but you will need a way to connect. There is an "unbranded" firmware package here: http://www.pausacafeone.it/download/original_dash/e1800/UTPS11.300.05.07.500_MAC13.305.06.02.500.rar

Unbranded in this case means it is the software that the device comes with when it is not bound to any carrier, meaning it should not contain any "crapware". Please note though, that the version might be older than your current one. 
The page (http://www.pausacafeone.it/content/original_dash.asp) also provides TIM branded software in case you need to restore it.

**Please note that doing this does not remove SIM-lock. If your device is sim-unlocked, you can use a carrier-branded connection manager with any sim-card, as long as the APN settings reflect it.**

Another way would be to use windows network connection.
To use that do this:

1. Remove the PIN code from your simcard
2. Install the original connection manager and drivers
3. Change the default APN settings to those of your new provider and connect at least once.
4. Uninstall the "crapware" and connection manager.
5. The network will now show in Network and sharing center
6. Right click the connection and select "connect". Your device should now connect without a connection manager.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way for me to check whether or not the device is sim-locked before going through this process? Or will the flashing of the firmware remove any sim lock anyway?

Comment: @GJ. If the device was given to you by your provider, it is almost certainly locked to that provider. As I already wrote in the bold section of the answer, flashing will not influence the sim-lock in any way. You can check by inserting a sim-card belonging to a different provider and then checking what the connection manager says. It should inform you and ask for an unlock code if the device is sim-locked.